# Не работает мягкий знак в INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
                            if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
                              $img_type = substr($_FILES['img_upload']['type'], 0, 5);
                              $img_size = 2*1024*1024;
                              //$tope = $_POST['tops'];
                              $category = $_POST['category'];
                              $name = $_POST['name'];
                              $date = $_POST['date'];
                              $comment = $_POST['comment'];
                              $txtnews = $_POST['txtnews'];
                              if(!empty($_FILES['img_upload']['tmp_name']) and $img_type === 'image' and $_FILES['img_upload']['size'] <= $img_size){ 
                              $img = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['img_upload']['tmp_name']));
                              $link->query("INSERT INTO news(img,date,comment,category,name,text) VALUES (`$img`,`$date`,`$comment`,`$category`,`$name`,`$txtnews`)");
                              echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url= /admin/news'>";
                              }
                            }
```

Существует следующий запрос в БД, всё создает отлично, но не добавляет любой текст с мягким знаком. В логах сайта чисто, что мог упустить?

Comment: Не добавляет в смысле целиком строка не добавляется?

Comment: В общем начать надо с нормального выполнения запроса и получения сообщения об ошибке